# Afinal para que serve a função repr no python?

Tags: python, funções

Sou meio novato em python e queria saber para que realmente serve essa função tão confusa, procurei em varios sites porém nenhum tem realmente dizendo para que serve ela

Comment: Um jeito fácil de lembrar: `print()` é pro usuário, `repr()` é pro programador.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`__repr()__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) serve para representar um objeto como uma `string`. Não precisa ser chamado diretamente. Toda vez que o Python precisa resolver um objeto como `string`, `__repr__()` será chamado automaticamente.

Vários tipos de objetos implementam `__repr__()` por padrão. Para objetos, normalmente `__repr__()` devolve a descrição e a referência em memória para o objeto.

A grande vantagem de `__repr__()` é justamente poder reescrevê-lo, [como fiz aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143267/imprimir-uma-lista-de-objetos-como-string-em-python/143269#143269). Ao invés de escrever o objeto como `<tipo + referência>`, você pode formatar sua `string` da maneira como bem entender:

```
class MeuObjeto(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor1 = 1
        self.valor2 = "2"

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.valor1) + ", " + self.valor2
```

Teste:

```
>>> o = MeuObjeto()
>>> o
1, 2
```

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 5):

O `repr` chama o método interno `__repr__` do objeto. A ideia dele é retornar uma representação como string de qualquer objeto - *mas pensando antes no programador* do que no usuário final do programa. Sobretudo é o `repr` que é chamado para cada resultado de expressão quando usamos o Python no modo interativo.

Assim, por exemplo, para uma string numa variável `a`, `repr(a)` retorna a string, mas com aspas simples em volta. Em contraste, `str(a)` mostra o objeto como string, mas numa forma que seja amigável de ser mostrada para o usuário, quando o programa estiver em execução. (Ou seja, o conteúdo da string, sem as aspas). Veja a diferença:

```
>>> a = "maçã"
>>> a  # internamente, o Python chama o "a.__repr__"
'maçã'
>>> print(a) # internamente, o Python (o código no "print") chama "a.__str__"
maçã
```

Via de regra, para objetos simples, built-in, havia a idaia de que se você copiasse a saída do `repr` e colasse como texto num terminal Python ou programa, você recriaria o objeto inicial de volta. Isso vale para strings, listas, dicionários, tuplas e sets - e você pode criar `repr`s de seus próprios objetos de forma que também valha pra eles. Mas o `__repr__` padrão mostra o nome da classe e o ID da instância (que no Python é igual o endereço de memória do objeto, mas isso é um detalhe de implementação): ou seja, não é possível recriar o objeto "repr"esentado por padrão, mas pode-se distinguir uma instância de outra olhando-se os seus `repr`s no terminal.

**Diferença entre `__repr__` e  `repr`**

Por fim, vale notar que todo objeto em Python tem um método `__repr__` - por que o o `object`, raiz de todos os objetos em Python tem um - e esse método é chamado automaticamente em várias situações: para ter uma forma de texto de um objeto para uma sessão interativa de Python, uma representação de texto a ser incluída de forma recursiva numa representação de texto de outro objeto, que contenha o objeto inicial, e algumas outras.

Já o método "built-in" `repr` é a forma de se chamar explicitamente os `__repr__` de um objeto quando queremos fazer isso. Assim como o `len` pode chamar o método `__len__` e também para `hash` e `__hash__`, `next` e `__next__` - a idéia é que essas funções built-in funcionem praticamente como operadores unários para acessar essas funcionalidades que os objetos tem e que são escritas na forma de métodos com os "nomes mágicos", com dois underscores. (Em textos não oficiais - como e-mails, cursos, e tutorais, você vai ver esses métodos sendo chamados de métodos "dunder" - uma contração de "double-underscore".)

E por fim, vale dizer que quando é solicitada a representação como string de um objeto, com `str`, o Python busca primeiro o método `__str__` - mas ao contrário do `__repr__` nem todos os objetos tem um método `__str__`padrão. (A classe `object` não implementa `__str__`) então a função built-n `str` ao não encontrar o  `__str__` chama o `__repr__` do objeto para ter sua representação como string.  Esse é um dos motivos de ser preferível chamar os métodos built-in a chamar os métodos "dunder" diretamente - mesmo que para o repr não haja quase nenhuma diferença entre fazer uma coisa e outra.

Em Python2 tinhamos agravantes do tipo: o método `__repr__` sempre tinha que retornar uma string, não um texto unicode. E os objetos, além do método `__str__` podiam implementar também o `__unicode__`. Ademais, o `repr` de strings transformavam qualquer caractere não ASCII em uma sequência de escape do tipo "\0xPython 3 simplificou bastante tudo isso.

Comment: valeu professor!, só pude ver agora, obrigado!