# Strings em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sei o básico de codificação de *strings* em Python, mas não ainda não consigo avançar e concluir toda a exigência do enunciado.
Não sei codificar as quantidades que exige na questão.

Segue enunciado:

Leia strings do teclado até que uma string vazia seja lida. 
Escreva em tela :

- (A)  a quantidade de vogais lidas;
- (B) a quantidade de dígitos lidos;
- (C) qual foi a string de maior comprimento lida. Caso haja empate, escreva uma delas;
- (D) a quantidade de strings palíndromes lidas.

Definição:

Uma string é dita `palíndrome` se e somente se, quando lida do primeiro para o último caractere for igual a string lida do último para o primeiro caractere.

Por exemplo:

`“AMA”`, `“POP”`, `“SOCORRAMMESUBINOONIBUSEMMARROCOS”`, `“”` e `“Z”` são palíndromes.

Comment: `len(minha_string)` dá lhe o tamanho da string. Ainda assim a sua questão está vaga. Tentar dar exemplos mais concretos do que pretende, de preferência com algum código que já tenha escrito

Comment: M.xy, vi que atualizou completamente a pergunta, mas mesmo assim não postou nenhum código. Mesmo com as respostas atuais você não conseguiu entender nem o mínimo para tentar? Se for, por favor, descreva suas dúvidas na pergunta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá. Vou fazer o exemplo mais simples possível, pois acho que assim fica mais fácil de entender. Depois é com você incrementar, fazer testes e aprender mais.

> Como codificar leitura de strings do teclado até que uma string vazia
> seja lida?

```
x = 'algo'
 
while x != '':
    x = input()
```

> Como escrever em tela as quantidades de letras de uma string?

```
string = "minha string"

print(len(string))
```

ou ainda, caso você prefira loop:

```
string = "minha string"
cont = 0

for x in range(string.__len__()):
    if string[x] != 0:
        cont +=1

print('Minha string tem {} caracteres' .format(cont))
```

Adendo: Vi em outra pergunta que você está bem perdida com a linguagem. Não se preocupe, isso é normal e todo mundo tem que começar do 0 um dia.

Comment: pq não usar print(len(string))

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca Explicação completa do porquê usar o .__len__ você encontra nesta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201701/afinal-para-que-serve-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-repr-no-python/201751#201751, mas em resumo, usando o seu método ou o meu método vai dar no mesmo já que, internamente, o Python vai interpretar com o .__len__ pois este é o método built-in

Comment: Realmente não há necessidade de utilizar o método `__len__`. Ou melhor, ele até prejudica o código quando comparado com a função `len` pois prejudica a legibilidade. E você não precisa do `range` para iterar sobre string, elas são iteraveis por si só naturalmente.

Comment: Como faz pra iterar diretamente com ela? Não sabia dessa, mas vou alterar o código

Comment: O correto é usar a função `len` - a ideia é que o Python sempre vai chamar os métodos mágicos apropriados de uma classe quando existirem. Então `next` em vez de `.__next__`, `str` em vez de `__str__`,usar o operador `in`  em vez de chamar `__contains__`, etc.

Comment: Assisto as aulas do Guanabara sim e estou gostando... mas ainda estou organizando os estudos para avançar mais. Agradeço os comentários. Me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Espero que essas aulas não incentivem o uso de `__len__` e semelhantes

Answer (score 2):

Se a intenção, que não ficou clara na pergunta, for, de fato a leitura de múltiplos textos do usuário até que o mesmo não digite algo, você deverá fazer um laço de repetição infinito até que a condição de parada seja satisfeita. De certa forma, é o que o código da outra resposta faz, porém, na minha opinião, não é a melhor maneira a se fazer.

```
x = 'algo'

while x != '':
    x = input()
```

Podemos supor que o leitor, inicialmente, não saberá que o objeto `x` será o responsável por receber o texto do usuário. Logo na primeira linha `x` recebe um valor constante. Ao ler, é natural pensar algo como "`x` recebe este valor porque em algum lugar irá precisar utilizá-lo" (o que já é uma interpretação errada do código, mas o leitor não saberia disso ainda). Na próxima linha, há o laço de repetição com a condição `x != ''` e, obviamente, o leitor pensará algo como "mas se `x` é constante, ele sempre será diferente de `''`, então esse laço será infinito?", o que, de novo, será uma interpretação errada do código. Somente ao ler a última linha, onde `x` recebe a entrada do usuário, que o código fará sentido.

Como não há como prever quantas vezes o usuário irá entrar com um texto diferente de vazio, o correto é criar o laço infinito com `while True`; depois, você faz a leitura da entrada do usuário e faz a verificação, se for um texto vazio, pare o laço. O código ficaria:

```
while True:
    x = input("Digite algo:")
    if not x:
        break
    print("Tamanho do texto", len(x))
```

Assim como comentado, foi utilizado a função `len` para obter o tamanho do texto.